# url not found after adjusting htacess file

Tags: .htaccess

I have adjusted a htacess to the following and works fine for the home page but if click the about page or any other page, it says the requested url /about was not found on this server but it's on the ftp server, the htacess coding is below

```
   ## EXPIRES CACHING ##
   <IfModule mod_expires.c>

   </IfModule>
   ## EXPIRES CACHING ##

   <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts

   </IfModule>

   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^1ststopcleaning.co.uk$
   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.1ststopcleaning.co.uk/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

   # external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(about)\.php[\s?] [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
```

I should have done a backup first of the htaccess file before adjusting it, can anyone help please, it's hosted on 123 reg but they can't help

Comment: So what is `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(about)\.php[\s?]` mean to express? We cannot somehow magically fix it without you telling us what you want to do...

Comment: I put that in for seo so it does think there is duplicate pages for example /about and about.php

I was told to do that or can it be removed?

Comment: What good should "duplicate pages" do? Either you have content or you don't. Stop trying to trick a search engine, you will lose. Use an internal rewriting if you want seo friendly URLs.

Comment: ok I have removed them lines from the htacess file but main worry is the url not found issue when clicking on the about page or any other page

Comment: Think I have solved it now

Comment: We cannot help here, you did not specify any information about your file system layout and the like. We cannot _guess_ all that.